# My android application crashes at second time I open it

Tags: android, multithreading

I use a contentView "gameView" it extends a SurfaceView and I use a thread to have a permanent loop to my game, my onCreate() method is

```
public class mainclass extends Activity {
GameView game;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    game = new GameView(this);
    setContentView(game);
}
```

the crash logcat is

```
05-09 09:35:06.378: W/dalvikvm(9664): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:359)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:385)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at superBill.Mbiz.Egypt.GameView.<init>(GameView.java:87)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at superBill.Mbiz.Egypt.SuperBillActivity.onCreate(SuperBillActivity.java:20)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-09 09:35:06.388: E/AndroidRuntime(9664):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Note: this crash happens at second time but third one is ok, fourth one crashes, five is ok and so on.

Comment: Provide some logs please

Comment: I'm guessing the crash is somewhere in your GameView class. Post the logcat and the GameView class so we can better figure out what's wrong

Comment: @dymmeh: I have posted it, is it enough ?

Comment: @AlaaEldin - According to your logcat you are trying to load an image that's too large. Try to slim down your images or down-sample them

Comment: @dymmeh: as I told you, it doesn't happen at the first time I run the app. but it happens when I close it then open again.
so that, I think it has nothing to do with image size.

Comment: @AlaaEldin - Logcat is your friend. It is telling you exactly what is happening which is "OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget". Your image is too big. Plain and simple. The reason it happens when you close and open it is likely you already are allocating a certain amount of memory to your application on your first run. You close it (likely just pause it) and reopen it and reload the image. When you reopen the application you already are using a certain amount of memory from your first run. you likely are trying to reload your image and then exceeding the amount of memory available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dymmeh: My code was

```
@Override
          public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
        {
            boolean retry = true;
            mythread.setRunning(false);
            while (retry) {

                   try {
                            mythread.join();
                            retry = false;
                       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   }
            }
     }
```

and that what caused what you said, I replaced it with

```
    @Override
          public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
        {
            mythread.setRunning(false);
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

now, everything is going well, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your surfaceCreated method for your GameView, you need to recreate the gamethread, since you likely let it die with gamethread.join() in your surfaceDestroyed method.  Something like this:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (gamethread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
        gamethread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);
        gamethread.setRunning(true);
        gamethread.start();
    } else if (gamethread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW) {
        gamethread.setRunning(true);
        gamethread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my code:
        `SurfaceHolder mySurfaceHolder;

    mySurfaceHolder = getHolder();

     mySurfaceHolder.addCallback(new Callback() 


{

    @Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
{
 boolean retry = true;
 mythread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry) {
       try {
              mythread.join();
             retry = false;
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  }
                  }
         }
 @Override
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
   {
    mythread.setRunning(true);
    mythread.start();
   }
`